# How to get source of rss feedChannel SyndEntry message in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, rss, spring-integration, feed, channel

I have a rss feed reader using spring integration. I want to learn source of a rss item.

Example item:

- title: "Top general: More ground troops needed in Libya"
- link: "cnn.com/blabla"
- pubDate: "2016-06-22 10:10:10"

I want to know in which rss link send me this item because I set it in init() function.

Result: http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss

Here is my feed channel config.

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel feedChannel() {
return new QueueChannel(500);
}
```

This is dynamic feedChannel creater. I read rss links from DB and create channel.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception{

List<RssLink> rssLinks = rssLinkService.findAll();

if(rssLinks != null && rssLinks.size() > 0 )
{
  for(RssLink rss : rssLinks) {
    QueueChannel channel = (QueueChannel) context.getBean("feedChannel");
    SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = new SourcePollingChannelAdapter();
    adapter.setApplicationContext(context);
    adapter.setBeanName("adapter." + rss.getSource().getName());

    FeedEntryMessageSource source = new FeedEntryMessageSource(new URL(rss.getLink()), rss.getSource().getName());
    source.setApplicationContext(context);
    source.setBeanName(rss.getSource().getDomain());
    source.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    source.afterPropertiesSet();

    adapter.setSource(source);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(channel);
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(300000);
    adapter.setTrigger(trigger);

    adapter.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(100);
    adapter.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    adapter.afterPropertiesSet();
    adapter.start();
  }
}
}
```

And this is the reader of the items in a channel.

```
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "feedChannel")
public void feedChannel(Message<SyndEntry> message) {
  SyndEntry payload = message.getPayload();
  MessageHeaders header = message.getHeaders();
  Feed feed = new Feed();
  feed.setLink(payload.getLink());
  feed.setTitle(payload.getTitle());
  //feed.setSource(I don't know which rss link send me this item);
}
```

So I want go get FeedEntryMessageSource of payload in ServiceActivator in order to know the item belongs which rss link. I set it 'rss.getSource().getName()' in this line :

```
FeedEntryMessageSource source = new FeedEntryMessageSource(new URL(rss.getLink()), rss.getSource().getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a direct link between `rss.getLink()` and `rss.getSource().getName()`. So, how about to go the way in your `@ServiceActivator` like `payload.getSource().getUri()` and retrieve a desired `name` from your `rssLinkService`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but payload.getSource() is null for all feeds. am I missing sth?